# JFace TreeViewer with initial expand on specific element types

Tags: swt, jface

I want to set some of the elements of the TreeViewer as being expanded by default.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

`TreeViewer` provides several methods you could use depending on your requirements:

- `setExpandedElements(..)`
- `setExpandedState((..)`
- `setExpandedTreePaths(..)`
- `setAutoExpandLevel(..)`

Comment: Hi,I can't use setExpandedElements because this method requires the concrete instance Objects that are in the Tree, which I don't have at compile. Also the treePaths are generated at runtime, I don't have acces to them at compile time. I would need something like setExpandedElementsType(ClassName)

Comment: Such a method does not exist. I assume you have access to the model at runtime? Why don't you iterate over each object in the model, check its type and then call `setExpandedState(..)` where appropriate?